# ORACLE - Custom ORDER BY to order pairs of data rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this.

```
|DATE      |VOUCHER_NO|CURRENCY|AMOUNT|DESCRIPTION|JOURNAL_TYPE|COA_NO  |

|03/30/2016|0000000001|USD     |2000  |ABCD       |CREDIT      |150001  |
|03/30/2016|0000000001|USD     |2000  |ABCD       |DEBIT       |150001  |
|03/30/2016|0000000002|USD     |1500  |ABCD       |CREDIT      |150002  |
|03/30/2016|0000000002|USD     |1000  |ABCD       |DEBIT       |150002  |
|03/30/2016|0000000002|USD     |500   |ABCD       |DEBIT       |150002  |
|03/30/2016|0000000003|USD     |4000  |ABCD       |CREDIT      |150003  |
|03/30/2016|0000000003|USD     |2000  |ABCD       |DEBIT       |150003  |
|03/30/2016|0000000003|USD     |1000  |ABCD       |DEBIT       |150003  |
|03/30/2016|0000000003|USD     |500   |ABCD       |DEBIT       |150003  |
|03/30/2016|0000000003|USD     |500   |ABCD       |DEBIT       |150003  |
```

I have to sort the table by the greatest Amount, with Journal Type Credit first. And it has to be followed by its Debit based on the Voucher_No (without concerning the Debit's amount),  then next to the second greatest amount, like this.

```
|DATE      |VOUCHER_NO|CURRENCY|AMOUNT|DESCRIPTION|JOURNAL_TYPE|COA_NO  |

|03/30/2016|0000000003|USD     |4000  |ABCD       |CREDIT      |150003  |
|03/30/2016|0000000003|USD     |2000  |ABCD       |DEBIT       |150003  |
|03/30/2016|0000000003|USD     |1000  |ABCD       |DEBIT       |150003  |
|03/30/2016|0000000003|USD     |500   |ABCD       |DEBIT       |150003  |
|03/30/2016|0000000003|USD     |500   |ABCD       |DEBIT       |150003  |
|03/30/2016|0000000001|USD     |2000  |ABCD       |CREDIT      |150001  |  
|03/30/2016|0000000001|USD     |2000  |ABCD       |DEBIT       |150001  | 
|03/30/2016|0000000002|USD     |1500  |ABCD       |CREDIT      |150002  |
|03/30/2016|0000000002|USD     |1000  |ABCD       |DEBIT       |150002  |
|03/30/2016|0000000002|USD     |500   |ABCD       |DEBIT       |150002  |
```

How to do that? If I ordered first by amount, the Debit ones will scatter to below, and if I ordered first by voucher_no, it will not be ordered by amount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `ORDER BY` a *group sum* first, like this

```
ORDER BY
   MAX(AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY VOUCHER_NO) DESC, -- voucher with highest amount first
   VOUCHER_NO,  -- all rows of that voucher
   CASE WHEN JOURNAL_TYPE = 'CREDIT' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, -- credit first
   AMOUNT DESC
```

Comment: Will this sort `credit` before `debit` for particular voucher?

Comment: @sql_dummy: If you want `credit` first you must add another column, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: He dint ask voucher with greatest amount . He asked voucher that has greatest credit amount.

Comment: @sql_dummy: The OP is the only one who knows exactly what he wants. And embedding the `CASE` within `MAX` is not difficult...

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
with your_table as (select to_date('30/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 1 voucher_no, 'USD' currency, 2000 amount, 'ABCD' description, 'Credit' journal_type, 150001 coa_no from dual union all
                    select to_date('30/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 1 voucher_no, 'USD' currency, 2000 amount, 'ABCD' description, 'Debit' journal_type, 150001 coa_no from dual union all
                    select to_date('30/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 2 voucher_no, 'USD' currency, 1500 amount, 'ABCD' description, 'Credit' journal_type, 150002 coa_no from dual union all
                    select to_date('30/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 2 voucher_no, 'USD' currency, 1000 amount, 'ABCD' description, 'Debit' journal_type, 150002 coa_no from dual union all
                    select to_date('30/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 2 voucher_no, 'USD' currency, 500 amount, 'ABCD' description, 'Debit' journal_type, 150002 coa_no from dual union all
                    select to_date('30/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 3 voucher_no, 'USD' currency, 4000 amount, 'ABCD' description, 'Credit' journal_type, 150003 coa_no from dual union all
                    select to_date('30/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 3 voucher_no, 'USD' currency, 2000 amount, 'ABCD' description, 'Debit' journal_type, 150003 coa_no from dual union all
                    select to_date('30/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 3 voucher_no, 'USD' currency, 1000 amount, 'ABCD' description, 'Debit' journal_type, 150003 coa_no from dual union all
                    select to_date('30/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 3 voucher_no, 'USD' currency, 500 amount, 'ABCD' description, 'Debit' journal_type, 150003 coa_no from dual union all
                    select to_date('30/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 3 voucher_no, 'USD' currency, 500 amount, 'ABCD' description, 'Debit' journal_type, 150003 coa_no from dual)
-- End of mimicking your table with data in. See SQL below:
select *
from   your_table
order by max(amount) over (partition by voucher_no) desc,
         journal_type,
         amount desc;

DT         VOUCHER_NO CURRENCY     AMOUNT DESCRIPTION JOURNAL_TYPE     COA_NO
---------- ---------- -------- ---------- ----------- ------------ ----------
30/03/2016          3 USD            4000 ABCD        Credit           150003
30/03/2016          3 USD            2000 ABCD        Debit            150003
30/03/2016          3 USD            1000 ABCD        Debit            150003
30/03/2016          3 USD             500 ABCD        Debit            150003
30/03/2016          3 USD             500 ABCD        Debit            150003
30/03/2016          1 USD            2000 ABCD        Credit           150001
30/03/2016          1 USD            2000 ABCD        Debit            150001
30/03/2016          2 USD            1500 ABCD        Credit           150002
30/03/2016          2 USD            1000 ABCD        Debit            150002
30/03/2016          2 USD             500 ABCD        Debit            150002
```

N.B., if you're going to be using this query in a subquery, obviously you'll have to add the `max(amount) over (partition by voucher_no)` into the select column list in order to expose that column to the outer query.

---

ETA. If you could have the case where the debit amounts were greater than the credit amounts, and you're after the rows for the voucher code with the highest credit amount to be displayed first, then change:

```
max(amount) over (partition by voucher_no)
```

to

```
max(case when journal_type = 'Credit' then amount end) over (partition by voucher_no)
```

Comment: He dint ask voucher with greatest amount . He asked voucher that has greatest credit amount.

Comment: Just assume a case there is `voucher1  debit  4000` also `voucher2  credit  3000` according to him `voucher2` has to come above `voucher1`

Comment: I was working on the assumption that a) there is only one credit per voucher code and b) that the debit amounts can never exceed the credit amount. I have updated my answer to add in the extra restriction, should it be required.

Comment: And, actually, the OP said `I have to sort the table by the greatest Amount, with Journal Type Credit first`, which - due to the comma - is ambiguous. It's up to the OP to decide what they want to use.

Comment: Thank you @sql_dummy and Boneist, again, for answering my question, sorry if it wasn't clear. It worked. The data should be having one credit for each voucher_no, and its debit amount can never exceed the credit amount.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but once check this

```
     SELECT * from ... ORDER BY JOURNAL_TYPE asc, AMOUNT asc;
```

Edit1:-Misunderstood your question, let me re-edit my answer.
Edit2:- The correct answer is already posted by user dnoeth
Note:- This is not the correct answer